# fileReference browse from js, simulate keypress in flash workaround

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, external, filereference

I am trying to call fileReference.browse from outside the flash SWF, i read some articles that said normally it's imposible due to Flash 10 security stuff.. so i was wondering isnt it posible to send a command from js to flash which will simulate a keypress inside the flash, which (this keypress) will trigger the fileReference.

Thank you in advance,
Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible (it would create quite a serious security risk). You can confirm this by checking any uploader module out there that uses Flash's FileReference... all of them use either a transparent flash overlay to register the click or the upload button itself is a customizable SWF (until recently gmail used a transparent overlay, now it uses native uploads I think).

Comment: i've tried native uploads but ajax uploading stops working sometimes, it blocks on like 60% of the upload