# why call flash function from javascript work but FileReference don't work in flash?

Tags: javascript, actionscript, filereference, addcallback

I need call flash function from javascript. I use flash.external and addCallback to do this. all things work well but when I use FileReference in my flash, function did not open my browser ...

please see below describtion:
I call my function in javascript with this code:
`<input type="button" value="Browse" onclick="sendToFlash('Hello World! from HTML');" />`
you can see all my HTML as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload test</title>
</head>
<script>
function hello (size) {
    alert ("size hast: " + size);
}

function sendToFlash(val){
    var flash = getFlashObject();
    flash.new_browser(val);
}

var flash_ID = "Movie2";
var flash_Obj = null;
function getFlashObject(){
    if (flash_Obj == null){
        var flashObj;
        if (navigator.appName.indexOf( "Microsoft" ) != -1){
           flashObj = window[flash_ID];
        } 
        else{
           flashObj = window.document[flash_ID];
        }
        flash_Obj = flashObj;
    }
    return flash_Obj;
}
</script>

  <body>
    <center>

    <embed width="560" height="410" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    flashvars="sampleVars=loading vars from HTML" 
    salign="" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" allowfullscreen="false" menu="true" name="Movie2" 
    bgcolor="#ffffff" devicefont="false" wmode="window" scale="showall" loop="true" play="true" 
    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" 
    quality="high" src="Movie2.swf">

    </center>

    <input type="button" value="Browse" onclick="sendToFlash('Hello World! from HTML');" />
  </body>
</html>
```

when I click `Browse` in html page, javascript call sendToFlash function and `SendToFlash` function send my string (Hello World! from HTML) to flash.
in flash I get this string with below code:

```
resultsTxtField.text = "";
uploadButton.onPress = function () {
   return browse_file("Hello World! from Flash");
}

import flash.external.*;
ExternalInterface.addCallback("new_browser", this, browse_file);


function browse_file (my_test_val) {
    _root.resultsTxtField.text = "val: " + my_test_val;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    var fileTypes:Array = new Array();
    var imageTypes:Object = new Object();
    imageTypes.description = "Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png)";
    imageTypes.extension = "*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.png";
    fileTypes.push(imageTypes);

    var fileListener:Object = new Object();
    var btnListener:Object = new Object();
    var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
    fileRef.addListener(fileListener);
    fileRef.browse(fileTypes);

    fileListener.onCancel = function(file:FileReference):Void
    {
      _root.resultsTxtField.text += "File Upload Cancelled\n";
    }

    fileListener.onSelect = function(file:FileReference):Void
    {
      _root.resultsTxtField.text += "File Selected: " + file.name + " file size: "+ file.size + " file type: " + file.type;
      getURL("javascript:hello("+file.size+");");
    }
}
```

I have only one Scene and this code is on root of this Scene. and I have one movie clip named `uploadButton` and has only a rectangle that work as button in this sample.
when you click on rectangle `browse_file("Hello World! from Flash");` called and a browser open that you can select a photo to upload.
when you click on `browse` in html same process must do but as you see variable send to function but `browser` to select a photo did not open any more.
I try several ways. for example I set new function to open only `picture browser` or set new Scene or use gotoAndPlay and more but there is another problem.
you can download my source from below link:
http://www.4shared.com/zip/YTB8uJKE/flash_uploader.html

note that javascript `onclick="sendToFlash('Hello World! from HTML');"` don't work in direct opening. you must open it in localhost.
I'll be so so happy for any clue.
thanks so much
Reza Amya

Answer (score 0):

You can't programmatically call `browse()`, it has to be from a mouse click inside Flash: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse()

> In Flash Player 10 and Flash Player 9 Update 5, you can only call
>   this method successfully in response to a user event (for example, in
>   an event handler for a mouse click or keypress event). Otherwise,
>   calling this method results in Flash Player throwing an Error
>   exception.

Answer (score 0):

after a day reading I know that it is impossible for security reasons.
then you can't open file reference with `addCallback` javascript code any way. for more information read [fileReference browse from js, simulate keypress in flash workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323976/filereference-browse-from-js-simulate-keypress-in-flash-workaround?rq=1)

Thanks again
Reza Amya